# MRJob and mapreduce task partitioning over Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I am trying to perform a mapreduce job using the Python MRJob lib and am having some issues getting it to properly distribute across my Hadoop cluster. I believe I am simply missing a basic principle of mapreduce. My cluster is a small, one master one slave test cluster. The basic idea is that I'm just requesting a series of web pages with parameters, doing some analysis on them and returning back some properties on the web page.

The input to my map function is simply a list of URLs with parameters such as the following:

```
http://guelph.backpage.com/automotive/?layout=bla&keyword=towing
http://guelph.backpage.com/whatever/?p=blah
http://semanticreference.com/search.html?go=Search&q=red
http://copiahcounty.wlbt.com/h/events?ename=drupaleventsxmlapi&s=rrr
http://sweetrococo.livejournal.com/34076.html?mode=ffff
```

Such that the key-value pairs for the initial input are just key:None, val:URL.

The following is my map function:

```
def mapper(self, key, url):
'''Yield domain as the key, and (url, query parameter) tuple as the value'''

parsed_url = urlparse(url)
domain = parsed_url.scheme + "://" + parsed_url.netloc + "/"

if self.myclass.check_if_param(parsed_url):

    parsed_url_query = parsed_url.query
    url_q_dic = parse_qs(parsed_url_query)

    for query_param, query_val in url_q_dic.iteritems():

        #yielding a tuple in mrjob will yield a list
        yield domain, (url, query_param)
```

Pretty simple, I'm just checking to make sure the URL has a parameter and yielding the URL's domain as key and a tuple giving me the URL and the query parameter as value which MRJob kindly transforms into a list to pass to the reducer, which is the following:

```
def reducer(self, domain, url_query_params):

    final_list = []
    for url_query_param in url_query_params:

        url_to_list_props = url_query_param[0]
        param_to_list_props = url_query_param[1]

        #set our target that we will request and do some analysis on
        self.myclass.set_target(url_to_list_props, param_to_list_props)

        #perform a bunch of requests and do analysis on the URL requested
        props_list = self.myclass.get_props()

        for prop in props_list:

            final_list.append(prop)

    #index this stuff to a central db
    MapReduceIndexer(domain, final_list).add_prop_info()


    yield domain, final_list
```

My problem is that only one reducer task is run. I would expect the number of reducer tasks to be equal to the number of unique keys emitted by the mapper. The end result with the above code is that I have one reducer which runs on the master, but the slave sits idly and does nothing, which is obviously not ideal. I notice that in my output a few mapper tasks are started, but always only 1 reducer task. Other than that, the task runs smoothly and all works as expected.

My question is... what the heck am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding the reduce step or screwing up my key-value pairs somewhere?  Why are there not multiple reducers running on this job?

Update:  OK so from the answer given I increased mapred.reduce.tasks to higher (it was the default which I now realize is 1). This was indeed why I was getting 1 reducer. I now see 3 reduce tasks being performed simultaneously. I now have an import error on my slave that needs to be resolved but at least I am getting somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of reducers is totally unrelated to the form of your input data. For MRJob it looks like you need [bootstrap options](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/writing-and-running.html#bootstrap-time-configuration)

Comment: Hmm, if this is the case perhaps I don't understand the term "reduce tasks." In my view, if I have 3 unique keys output by the mapper the reduce function needs to run 3 distinct times to finish the mapreduce task entirely. To me this should be "3 reduce tasks" and those 3 tasks should be distributed across the cluster, is this not the case?

Comment: As an update, you were correct, thanks! I now have multiple reduce tasks running simultaneously. However, they ALL get sent to master and none to slave, argh!